# st_contains returning false when expected to return true

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis

would appreciate some help in this query, it's returning false while the point is definitely inside that polygon...what could be wrong?
thanks

```
SELECT ST_Contains( 
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT( 46.8176 24.7313 )',4326),
    ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((47.144234 24.14287,47.144234 24.129304,47.137339 24.129304,47.130444 24.129304,47.130444 24.14287,47.133892 24.14287,47.137339 24.14287,47.140787 24.14287,47.144234 24.14287))') 
)
```

Comment: Every first coordinate in your shape starts `47.`. Your `POINT` starts `46.`. Why are you sure the latter is "definitely inside" the former?

Comment: Similarly, the second coordinates for the shape are all of the form `24.1something`. Your point is `24.7313`.

Comment: Also, your first Geom specifies an SRID of 4326, the second doesn't specify any. Which I think in most systems makes them "incomparable" and so the results of contains would probably be nonsense anyway.

Comment: ah my bad, i gave the wrong polygon, i will follow your advice adding 4326 to the second as well, thanks